# How to draw a vertical line in a .NET chart

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, data-visualization

I would like to draw a vertical line along `x=0`. I've tried the code below, but instead of all the points being drawn with `x=0`, they are drawn with `x` values of `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, respectively. I am able to draw a vertical line at what appears to be any x value other than `0`.

The code below also sort of works if I change the `x` value of any of the points to something other than `0`. Is this some sort of bug with the Chart in .NET? Is there a way to draw a vertical line along `x=0`?

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType =  
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.FastLine;
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, 0);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, 2.5);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, 5);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, 10);
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(0, 20);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chart displays incorrectly when all x values are zero](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fb6da2c5-bb8e-40cc-bfe4-68bd76e1d826/chart-controls-faq?forum=MSWinWebChart#8009918f-a248-446f-9215-c29688f6cfa7)